# Translated url path to query params for nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Url `https://example.com/profile/chico`
must be understood by nginx as:
`https://example.com/profile/?username=chico` (the url that currently works).

`https://example.com/profile/` currently works as well, as it currently resolves to index.php, without the username param.

I currently have

```
location /profile/ {
    index /profile/index.php;
}
```

There are so many different things about this on the web and I didn't find specifically what I need.

Also tried

```
location /profile/ {
    rewrite ^/profile/(.*)$ /profile/?username=$1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
location /profile/ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/profile/(.+)$ /profile/index.php?username=$1 last;
    rewrite ^ /profile/index.php last;
}
```

If the first `rewrite` matches, the second `rewrite` is ignored. After the URI is rewritten with a `.php` extension, the processing moves to a different `location` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

EDIT: Added `try_files` block to handle static content.

Comment: Thanks, got closer to working, the page with a username var actually loads but the assets on the page result in a 404 (for example /profile/assets/js/main.js can't be found, same for images and css files)

Comment: Ok, didn't realise you had static content at that location. Answer updated.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.